# Detect when a dynamic body stops overlapping a sensor on Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics, collision, overlap

I'm making a game that is mostly based on a dynamic physics body and now I need to apply a force on that element when it is overlapping an other item (arrow) which is a sensor body.

I know that I can start applying the force as soon as a collision event with phase began happens on the arrow but, how can I detect when to stop applying this force?

Is there a way to know when the dynamic object is outside the bounds of the sensor body?

Comment: Can't you just use the respective phase "ended" given you are using phase "began"?

Comment: I tried that but it is called even when the dynamic body is still inside the sensor... And it is also called when the dynamic body sleeps inside it (tested when was just debugging the phases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after many tries and even after thinking on the Separating Axis Theorem, I made this on an easier way (since the SAT one was too slow to me):

```
element:addEventListener( "collision", function(event) 
    if (event.other.id=="ball") then
        if (event.phase=="began") then
            element.collision_counter=element.collision_counter+1
        elseif (event.phase=="ended") then
            element.collision_counter=element.collision_counter-1
        end
    end
end)
```

So, from what I understood, seems that `event.phase=="began"` is called each time that a collision on a `Shape` of a `Body` is verified and, `event.phase=="ended"` is called when the object does not collide with that same `Shape` anymore. Now, the "secret" that makes this code work well is the fact that if the object is still on collision on a `Body` but with another `Shape`, then `event.phase=="began"` is called first for the new `Shape` and only then the `event.phase=="ended"` is called.

After this and since I wanted to affect the velocity of my object while it was inside my `element` (that is an arrow on my case), I simply used the `Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", scene )` on my scene with this code below:

```
function scene:enterFrame()
    if (element.collision_counter>0) then
        local rad=math.rad(element.rotation)
        other_object:applyForce( 15, 0, other_object.x, other_object.y )
    end
end
```